# Counter in arrays c++

Tags: c++

i have a really simple code right there that counts how much values you need in arrays.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dm; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == c)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    };
```

But i need to make it a little bit tricky.I need to count number of same values. Imagine i have an array {4,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0,0,0} and i need to find how much "twins" there. So 3,2,1 are twins because they have only 1 exact friend.
I tried something like 2 fors and 2 counters but still have troubles. Thanks. Hope you understand what i mean by "twin". x and x are twins and y,y,y are not ( just in case)

Comment: Is your array always sorted?

Comment: Make a "map" object and store the counts in it

Comment: @slava yes from higher to lower if thats what you mean

Comment: Where do you want to store this info?

Comment: @vidorvistrom i thought about using 2 FORs and just keep that info in variable but couldnt do that correctly

Comment: Do you want to manipulate that info later on, or simply print them? In 1st case you will have to store it in a map, or a pair maybe. In second case simply iterate using 2 for loops and break the inner loop when counter is greater than 3. Just use crude logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without using additional array:

```
int twins_counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dm; i++)
{
    int counter = 0; // counter for elements 
    for (int j = 0; j < dm; j++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            if( j < i )
            {
                 break; // we have searched twin for this element already
            }
            counter++;
            if( counter > 2 )
            {
                break; // we meet element third time, it isn't twin
            }
        }
    }

    if( counter == 2 )
    {
          twins_counter++;
     }
};
```

For sorted (upwards or downwards) arrays one cycle is enough:

```
int twins_counter = 0;
int counter = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < dm; i++)
{
    if( arr[i] == arr[i-1] )
    {
         counter++;
     }
     else
     {
           if( counter == 2 )
           {
                 twins_counter++;
                 counter = 1;
           }
     }
}

// check last value
if( counter == 2 )
{
    twins_counter++;
}
```

Comment: For sorted array you can simplify this solution even more

Comment: Thanks but can you leave me a hint how i need to modify it, if i need to find for example only elements that exist 4 times in array, not 2 times like twins?

Comment: @AlexMIEL Just change 2 to 4 in if condition.

Comment: replace it in both place, or just use variable for needed value

Comment: "replace it in both place" that's why I do not like solutions with code duplicate

Answer (score 2):

I'd make a map that counts - for each individual number in the array - their occurrences. The code could look as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    const int numberOfElements = 12;

    int array[numberOfElements] = { 4,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0,0,0 };
    std::map<int,int> counts;
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        counts[array[i]]++;
    }
    for (auto x : counts) {
        if (x.second == 2) {
            cout << "pair: " << x.first << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If  - for some reason - the range of the elements is limited, you could also use a "plain" array for counting the occurrences. If, for example, the elements are in the range of `0..4`, you could use the following fragment:

```
const int numberOfElements = 12;
const int elementMax = 4;

int array[numberOfElements] = { 4,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0,0,0 };
int counts[elementMax+1] = {};
for (int i=0; i<numberOfElements; i++) {
    counts[array[i]]++;
}
for (int i=0; i <= elementMax; i++) {
    if (counts[i] == 2) {
        cout << "pair: " << i << endl;
    }
}
```

And if your array is sorted, than a solution without a counter-array could look as follows:

```
const int numberOfElements = 12;

int array[numberOfElements] = { 4,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0,0,0 };
int prev = -1;
int count = 0;
for (int i=0; i<numberOfElements; i++) {
    if (array[i] == prev) {
      count++;
    }
    else {
        if (count == 2) {
            cout << "pair: " << prev << endl;
        }
        count=1;
        prev = array[i];
    }
}
if (prev >= 0 && count==2) {
    cout << "pair: " << prev << endl;
}
```

Comment: The comments to the OP said the array is always sorted, so both of these are far too much work, memory usage, etc.

Comment: @Daniel H: the first ones are more general solutions, which I found worth stating; attached a solution for sorted arrays, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in one pass and use binary search for efficiency:

```
int arr[] = { 4,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0,0,0 };
int twins = 0;
for( auto i = std::begin( arr ); i != std::end( arr ); ) {
    auto next = std::upper_bound( i, std::end( arr ), *i, std::greater<int>() );
    if( std::distance( i, next ) == 2 ) ++twins;
    i = next;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/7kayQP)

In case there are not too many duplicates in the array `std::upper_bound` could be not efficient and can be easily replaced:

```
    auto next = std::find_if( std::next( i ), std::end( arr ), [i]( int n ) { return *i != n; } );
```

Comment: O(n) for your solution is n*log n because of binary search on every step of cycle. binary search isn't needed - see my solution.

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov You are trying to say that to fully scan array is more efficient than doing binary search? You need to rethink your O(n) estimation. It would be n*log n if I increase `i` by 1 and do binary search for every value.

Comment: If all values in array will be different your solution will be the same as we make binary search on each element. So O(n) of it is n*log n.

Comment: For sorted array one scan without any inner search is enough. So best solution for sorted array has O(n) = n

Comment: Your solution is better for case where there are only several different values in big sorted array. But it doesn't change O(n).

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov ok added variant that scans array once.